# UIImageView Zoom and Touch Image

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swift3, swift2

I have a big image and I want to show this image in ScrollView and I want to detect touched area with x and y coordinates of the image.

If I choose **'User Interaction Enabled'** of ScrollView, zoom is working but touchesBegan method doesn't working on ScrollView(It's working outside),
If I didn't choose **'User Interaction Enabled'** of ScrollView, zoom isn't working but **touchesBegan** method working on ScrollView and I'm getting coordinates but I can't zoom.

How can I solve this problem ?

Code :

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=7.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSize(width: 1424,height: 1410);
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    return self.imageView
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.imageView)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey BadCode have you solved your problem ? I am also facing the same issue  here.

Comment: Hi, yes i solved the problem. Firstly, you should enable user interaction for View and ScrollView in the View in XCode. Also, I added TapGestureRecognizer and I added this codes in viewDidLoad()
//start of the code
myGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapGestureExportAction(_:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(myGestureRecognizer)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//end of the code.

I created a function named tapGestureExportAction.

Comment: Thanks buddy I will try it as you suggested.